# Selenium: how to ignore more then 2 exception

Tags: scala, selenium

So i have this generic function that wait for my element base on `ExpectedCondition`:

```
def findMyElement(expectedCondition: (By) => ExpectedCondition[WebElement], by: By, timeOut: Long): WebElement = {

    createFluentWait(timeOut).until(expectedCondition(by))
    driver.findElement(by)
  }

 def createFluentWait(timeOut: Long): FluentWait[WebDriver] = {

    new FluentWait[WebDriver](driver)
      .withTimeout(timeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
      .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
      .ignoring(classOf[NoSuchElementException], (classOf[StaleElementReferenceException]))
  }
```

So my question is how to add another `Exceptions` to my `createFluentWait` function in order to avoid `Exception` before time out ? (ignoring gets only 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add another .ignoring call to your `createFluentWait` function. Which other exceptions were you wanting to ignore?

```scala
def createFluentWait(timeOut: Long): FluentWait[WebDriver] = {

    new FluentWait[WebDriver](driver)
        .withTimeout(timeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .ignoring(classOf[NoSuchElementException])
        .ignoring(classOf[StaleElementReferenceException])
        .ignoring(classOf[SomethingElseException])
}
```

Comment: Is it good to add several exception ? or maybe to avoid it ? i want this in order to try until time out reached, i want also ignore ElementNotVisibleException and NoSuchElementException

Comment: It depends on what exception you are getting, why that's happening and if that's expected or not. I often find that `NoSuchElementException` and `StaleElementReferenceException` are the only two I use.

Comment: Is the exceptions order also have any issue ?

Comment: No, the order doesn't matter. Have a look at the documentation for [FluentWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can concat another `ignoring`

```
def createFluentWait(timeOut: Long): FluentWait[WebDriver] = {

    new FluentWait[WebDriver](driver)
        .withTimeout(timeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .ignoring(classOf[NoSuchElementException, (classOf[StaleElementReferenceException]))
        .ignoring(classOf[NullPointerException, (classOf[StaleElementReferenceException]))
}
```